# Custom URL Protocol for Invoking Application: What if the key is not found in registry?

Tags: c#, html, browser, registry, url-scheme

I have been trying to invoke an application from browser using Custom URI Scheme. This article helped me how to set it up. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/aa767914.

What if I delete the key in registry manually and ask the browser to invoke the application. In this case, the browser won't be able to invoke the application. Here how can I notify the browser or user that the key is not found in registry.
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: In IE/Edge you can do it via msLaunchUri(), googling for msLaunchUri polyfill yields https://gist.github.com/aaronk6/d801d750f14ac31845e8

Comment: @AlexK. I appreciate your help. But i am still looking for a generic solution. Thank you for your time. :)